# Correctly setting up parameters in C# when calling C++ DLL

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, dll, interop, dllimport

I've been tasked with putting a C# wrapper around an old C++ dll that has had the source mislaid. I do have some details of the dll:

```
enum DataItemType {DataItemType_String, DataItemType_Number, DataItemType_Date};

typedef struct Data_Item_Node_
{
    char *field_name;
    char *field_value;
    enum DataItemType field_type;
    struct Data_Item_Node_ *next;
} Data_Item_Node;

typedef struct Data_Item_List_
{
    Data_Item_Node *first;      // points to first item in the list
    Data_Item_Node *last;       // points to last item in the list
    long count;                 // number of data items in the list
    Data_Item_Node **index;     // sorted array of pointers to the list items
    char *pDataDumpBuffer;      // pointer to a buffer used by the [*DumpData] command
} Data_Item_List;



extern "C" SAIL_IMP_EXP BOOL WINAPI Sail_Validate(const char *sail, const char *streams, const char *inserts)


extern "C" SAIL_IMP_EXP BOOL WINAPI Sail_GetStreamAndInserts(char *sail, Data_Item_List_ *data, char *stream, char inserts[][9], int insert_count)


extern "C" SAIL_IMP_EXP LONG WINAPI Sail_GetErrorMessage(LPSTR error, DWORD len)
```

As you can see, there are 3 methods I need to call. I've created a C# command line wrapper to test it with and used DLLImport to reference the exposed methods:

```
   class Program
    {

        [DllImport("Sail_.dll")]
        public static extern bool Sail_Validate(string sail, string streams, string inserts);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string p_sail = args[0];
            string p_streams = args[1];
            string p_inserts = args[2];

            try
            {
                bool Result = Sail_Validate(p_sail, p_streams, p_inserts);

                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + Result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This C# code seems to work so far for the one method it calls, but I've hit a bit of a brick wall at the next one 'Sail_GetStreamAndInserts', mainly with the Data_Item_List_ & 2 dimensional array parameters.

I'd be grateful for any help in how to define the parameters for the remaining methods.

Comment: Slight update to this - I've sussed out the multidimensional array part of this. I'll add an answer with how that was done once I've sorted out the biggy, which is Data_Item_List. I tried creating just a Node to pass through, but the definition contains a self referential pointer (*next). If I do that in C# it gives me a compilation error as struct is managed code and you can't put a reference to it even if its declared as unsafe.